# Linq JOIN, COUNT, TUPLE in C#

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have table with columns: A, B and other columns(not important for this)

for example

```
A           B           C         D
Peter      apple   
Thomas     apple
Thomas     banana
Lucy       null
```

How can I get list of tuples {A, count of B} using join?

For my table it is: {Peter, 1}, {Thomas, 2}, {Lucy, 0}

Thanks

Comment: `table.GroupBy(t => t.A).Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count(gg => gg != null) });`

Comment: ^ Above should be `.Count(gg => gg.B != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to just group by records on column A and count where B is not null

```
        var result = (from t1 in cartItems
                      group t1 by t1.A into t2
                      select new
                      {
                          t2.Key,
                          count = t2.Count(p=> p.B != null)
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: if in your sample `Table` is same, then you can't join on on `t1.A equal t2.B` because it always return empty, since A and B - different columns with different values

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned table, I assume it is `DataTable`.

You could use simple `Linq` statements for what you need. Query returns `List<Tuple>` and `Tuple` contains two fields **Item1** representing `Name` and **Item2** representing `Count`

```
var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row=>row.Field<string>("A"))
    .Select(s=> new Tuple<string, int>(s.Key, s.Count(c=>c!=null)))         
    .ToList();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YuVVot)